# How to deploy a scala play 2 app in OpenShift?

Tags: scala, playframework, openshift

Been googling around for some time already.
I have some java, nodejs, php, etc. applications deployed in openshift, and I want to deploy a scala play2.3 app now. I'm starting a new project and I really want to write it in scala with play. 
I need either a way to deploy a play 2.3 app in openshift, or another free hosting service that provides the same tools.
Thanks in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i know [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/java?lang=scala) hosting service let you deploy scala-play application. also it seems that OpenShift also provides the same [functionnality](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/196-scala).

Answer (score 0):

You may try following QuickStart: https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/198-play-framework